# Authenticating using Twitter's OAuth - do I need two Twitter applications? One Development and one Production?

Tags: authentication, oauth, twitter

I would like my users of my website to authenticate via Twitter's OAuth system.

Do i need to create TWO applications on the dev.twitter.com site? One for development and one for production?

Why I'm asking is because of the `website` and `callback url` text boxes :-

[image]

For development, i need to callback to my localhost .. while on live, it should be the live url. Secondly, the website domains are different. On my localhost machine, the website is `localhost.www.pewpew.com` while the live one will be `www.pewpew.com`

So do I need two applications?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you don't need to create two applications. You can set your production callback URL in the that field of the application. Then use `oauth_callback` ( https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5849#section-2.1 ) property of the OAuth actual request to set callback dynamically.

How to set it dependns on the library you use to sign requests, receive token/secret, etc. But Twitter definitely supports it.

Check also these: [Twitter O-Auth Callback url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1488278/twitter-o-auth-callback-url), [Twitter oauth_callback parameter being ignored!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2940528/twitter-oauth-callback-parameter-being-ignored/3351724#3351724)

Comment: Cheers! I'll give that a go (manually setting the oauth_callback parameter when i'm in 'dev' mode).